# Applying Angular 2 Animations through ngOnInit

Tags: animation, angular

Let's say I wanted a navigation bar to drop down from the top of the browser into place, once the app/website has been loaded in the browser.

Is it possible to handle that movement through the animations metadata of a given component?

Right now, I can make it do what I want, but I have to attach the action to a (click) of a button.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 state: string = 'firstpos';

 toggleStates() {
   this.state = (this.state === 'firstpos' ? 'secondpos' : 'firstpos');
 }

 ngOnInit () {
  this.state = 'secondpos';
 }

}
```

As shown above, when a button is clicked toggleStates() works and the element moves.  However, ngOnInit only immediately places the element in the second position without any movement or transition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly and how you want is unclear but as a workaround you can consider below solution,

```
ngOnInit () {
  setTimeout(()=>{
     this.state = 'secondpos';
  },5000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

`ngOnInit () {
  setTimeout(()=>this.state = 'secondpos');
}`